# Why did the feed ban me from chat?

Tags: bug, chat

I was just banned from chat over [this comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/messages/17035470/history), which, to my eye looks fairly innocuous.

[Comment history before someone blew it away](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcLN6.jpg)

[Clicking on the Feeds profile brought me to here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds)

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Instead of caching, we're blaming Feeds.

Comment: @GlenH7 http://i.imgur.com/Z9XozdK.png

Comment: For completeness, here was the history: http://i.imgur.com/h62dKUj.jpg

Comment: Clicking on Feeds brings me to http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-2/feeds

Comment: To ease debugging, [link to message in transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17035470#17035470).